# Reading a text file which contains an English dictionary to print the matching word meaning in python

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching

I have a text file which has an english dictionary with words listed like this:

```
Zymome (n.) A glutinous substance, insoluble in alcohol, resembling legumin;         -- 
now called vegetable fibrin, vegetable albumin, or gluten casein.

Zymometer (n.) Alt. of Zymosimeter

Zymophyte (n.) A bacteroid ferment.
```

As you can see the meanings are of multiple lines. Could anyone help me with a program to search for the word in the input in the text file and display the corresponding meaning of that word?

Code that I tried:

```
x=raw_input("Enter word: ")
with open('e:\\Python27\\My programs\\dictionary.txt') as file:    
    data = file.readlines()
    for line in data:
        if x in line:
            print line
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us some effort on your part, and we'll help when you get stuck.

Comment: what's the problem? the code should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
x = raw_input("Enter word: ")
with open('dictionary.txt') as file:
    data = file.read()

x_pos = data.find(x)
meaning= None
if x_pos == 0 or (x_pos != -1 and data[x_pos - 1] == '\n' and data[x_pos - 2] == '\n'):
    i = x_pos
    while i < len(data):
        if data[i] == '\n' and i > 0 and data[i - 1] == '\n':
            break
        meaning += data[i]
        i += 1

print meaning if meaning else "Not found"
```

or a regex-based solution:

```
import re


x = raw_input("Enter word: ").strip()
with open('d.txt') as file:
    data = '\n\n' + file.read() + '\n\n'

pattern = r'\n\n(' + x + r' .*?)\n\n'
pattern_compiled = re.compile(pattern, re.DOTALL)

res = pattern_compiled.search(data)
if res:
    print(res.group(1))
else:
    print('Not found')
```